# Marquee entire view android

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

Is there any way to Marquee a horizontal view in android? i.e. i have a horizontal view with 4 buttons and i want it to continuously scroll like marquee. Is there any way to execute it? This is the horizontal layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.learn2crack.tab.Slider" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp" >
    <include
      android:id="@+id/buttons_override"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      layout="@layout/slidecontent"/>
</HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```